# Laravel-Excel returns required error with all rows

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I am implementing [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) into my project and could not figure out the validation.

I try to upload the `xlsx` file with one row of data in it but still, the import throws `required` error.

Following is my `EventResultImport` code

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Data\EventResult;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;

class EventResultImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, WithHeadingRow
{
    use Importable;

    public function model(array $row)
    {
        HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');

        return new EventResult([
            'event_id' => $row[0],
            'event_name' => $row[1],
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            //'EventId' => 'required|numeric', Tried this
            //'*.EventId' => 'required|numeric', Tried this
            '0' => 'required|numeric'

        ];
    }
}
```

I get error on second-row event if there is numeric data in column `EventId`.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing WithHeadingRow, so the attributes must match:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'event_id' => 'required|numeric'
    ];
}
```

To skip nulls:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    if (!isset($row[0])) {
        return null;
    }

    return new User([
        'name' => $row[0],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Message says you are missing an ID on row 2 and you said your file has only one row, so maybe your file has leftover data on row 2.

Comment: I think you are right. How do i skip emptyrow from validating?

Comment: that skips the whole row if the first cell is blank.

Comment: Well... You are the one saying the first cell is required. :P

Comment: first cell is required but there are other cells in the row and if the first is empty it will always skip the whole row and not validate.

Comment: In general a row is a collection of fields that belongs to a single element. Isn't that the case for you? When you say the first cell is required, this means that your whole row is invalid if first row is not provided, that's exactly what the system should be doing, it's normal behaviour.  Maybe you can clarify what you are trying to achieve.